Read a csv archive on a array
I'm trying to read a archive csv with name, company, city, states, address, number, complement, neighborhood, cep and country, with a array like this:
`String path = "/home/arthur/Documentos/fe.csv";
List list = new ArrayList<>();
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))){
        String enderecoCsv = br.readLine();
        while (enderecoCsv != null){
            String[] fields = enderecoCsv.split(",");
            list.add(new Dates(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3], fields[4],
                    fields[5], fields[6], fields[7], fields[8], fields[9]));
            enderecoCsv = br.readLine();
        }
        for (Dates dates : list){
            System.out.println(dates.getCep());
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }`

i try to change de ";" to ",".

And what's the problem exactly? Please tell us the error you are experiencing or what you whant to achieve

I think that's a problem on the file "fe.csv". sorry for you lost time.

Try this and dont fail to get back to me if any issues
// Assuming the path to the CSV file is provided as a String
String path = "...";
List<Dates> list = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    // Skip the header row if it exists
    String headerRow = br.readLine();

    String enderecoCsv;
    while ((enderecoCsv = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = enderecoCsv.split(",", -1);  // Handle trailing commas

        // Validate data before creating Dates objects
        if (fields.length != 10) {
            System.out.println("Invalid data line: " + enderecoCsv);
            continue;  // Skip to the next line
        }

        // Validate field types if necessary (e.g., check for numbers, dates)

        Dates dates = new Dates(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3], fields[4],
                                 fields[5], fields[6], fields[7], fields[8], fields[9]);
        list.add(dates);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR: File not found at path: " + path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR: An I/O error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
}

// Assuming a getCep() method exists in the Dates class
for (Dates dates : list) {
    System.out.println(dates.getCep());
}


It was a file's error. There was too many "," on this file and the error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

was appearing
